# How can I get images to wrap with no vertical space?

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I'm pulling images that are of the same width, but not the same height. I'm trying to display them in rows with no added vertical space.

For example, if row 1 has images that are 100px 150px and 70px high respectively, I'd want the images on the second row to appear directly underneath each image at the respective height.

Right now, I have float set to left which works for the horizontal display. Adding a clear: left gives the desired effect but places everything in a single column. How do I get images wrapping to the left, but appearing vertically immediately below?

As things are, any images underneath the first 3 would all display at the same line height of the one beneath the 150px image with a large vertical space underneath the 100px and 70px images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more digging, it's a combination jQuery and CSS that makes what I was looking for possible. Specifically jQuery Masonry.

http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/basic-single-column.html

Answer (score 1):

If you display them as rows, the images will line up in rows, there is nothing that you can do about that.

I think that you rather want to display them in columns, that way the images in one column won't affect the images in the other columns. Just put columns beside each other by floating them, and images inside them.

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
  <img ... />
  <img ... />
  <img ... />
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img ... />
  <img ... />
  <img ... />
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img ... />
  <img ... />
  <img ... />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column { float: left; }
.column img { display: block; }
```

Comment: I'd considered that, but the number of images will vary (they're pulled dynamically) by page so it's difficult to style them by column/use clear to get them aligned vertically since I won't know in advance how many images will be in each column.

Comment: @user678537: Just put the first image in the first column, the second image in the second column, and so on. It's more difficult than just putting the images after each other, but that's what you need to do to get rid of the horisontal space.

Comment: It's all dynamic, none of the images are fixed or static from day to day. I might have 70 images one day and 100 the next, plus it will amount to a separate query for each image which I'm afraid is going to be a resource hog since the query to pull them is running through a few selectors to start with. I'm only insistent on it being handled through styling because I've seen it done on a website (copying their style elements didn't work though)

Comment: @user678537: If your server language is that limited, it would also be possible to change the layout using client script. That is likely what they used on the page where you saw it, and if so the reason why only copying the style didn't work. You could create three empty columns and list the images after, then put a script after that which moves the image elements into the columns.

Comment: It's not about the server language being limited. It's that I'm working with a large number of images where the quantity will vary day to day, and that right now I have a single query that returns all images from a given day. Going about it in the way you suggested would work, but if I have 100 images it would also mean 100 different queries to display each image which I find to be a waste when one query will do the job.

Comment: You're right on the client side language though, what I saw on the site I was looking at was a result of jQuery + CSS. Setting a container around the images (because I know how wide each one will be) takes care of the width without having to create columns.